# Given a string X and the reverse of that string,Y. Is the longest common sequence of X and Y always a palindrome?

Tags: string, algorithm, lcs

Our professor gave us the following problem:

```
Input
   A sequence of characters X = x1, x2, ... ,xn
Output
   The length of the longest sub-sequence of X that is a palindrome
```

My solution was:

```
 Take X and reverse it into the sequence Y = y1, y2, ... , yn
 Then perform LongestCommonSubsequence(X,Y)
```

He gave me partial credit and wrote,

```
"The LCS of X and reverse X is not necessarily a palindrome."
```

But I keep running the this algorithim (not mine by the way), with X and reverse X and all I get is palindromes.

```
/**
 ** Java Program to implement Longest Common Subsequence Algorithm
 **/

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

/** Class  LongestCommonSubsequence **/
public class  LongestCommonSubsequence
{    
/** function lcs **/
public String lcs(String str1, String str2)
{
    int l1 = str1.length();
    int l2 = str2.length();

    int[][] arr = new int[l1 + 1][l2 + 1];

    for (int i = l1 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = l2 - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j))
                arr[i][j] = arr[i + 1][j + 1] + 1;
            else 
                arr[i][j] = Math.max(arr[i + 1][j], arr[i][j + 1]);
        }
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (i < l1 && j < l2) 
    {
        if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) 
        {
            sb.append(str1.charAt(i));
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if (arr[i + 1][j] >= arr[i][j + 1]) 
            i++;
        else
            j++;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

How can I prove or disprove that the longest common sub-sequence of X and reverse X is or isn't a palindrome?

Comment: This link might help: http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Longest_palindromic_subsequence

Spoiler: LCS doesn't necessarily output **the** palindrome.

Comment: @coproc I think Tymur's link does provide a counterexample, read here http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Longest_palindromic_subsequence#LCS-based_approach

Comment: @גלעדברקן ok, right. Still I think that the LCS-algorithm of the OP would always return a palindrome (see also my answer).

Comment: @TymurGubayev Since the requirement is to output the *length* of the longest common subsequence, it's OK if there are other LCSs that are as long as the longest palindrome.

Comment: FWIW, I think you're right that the algorithm you've posted always outputs a palindrome. I wrote a quick program to test that hypothesis over every distinct string (up to isomorphism) of length <= 10, and in all cases the returned LCS was a palindrome.

Comment: The link gives what appears to be a proof that any longest palindromic subsequence must be an LCS of the string and its reverse (so the set of longest palindromic subsequences is a subset of the LCSs).

Answer (score 1):

For `X = 0,1,2,0,1` we have `Y = reverse(X) = 1,0,2,1,0` and one of the longest subsequences is `0,2,1`. So your proposition does not hold in general. But it is still possible that the LCS returned by the algorithm given in the question is always a palindrome. In my example a systematic enumeration of all LCS-s looks like this: `0,1,0`, `0,2,1`, `0,2,0`, `1,2,0`, `1,2,1`, `1,0,1` - and the first LCS is indeed a palindrome. But I was not able to proof in general yet. So I think that actually both (professor and you) are right: Although there can be a LCS of `X` and `reverse(X)` that is not a palindrome, most (actually: straight forward) implementations of an LCS-algorithm would always return a palindrome for `X` and `reverse(X)`. (Full proof still missing)